# CSS parse errors from a generated stylesheet

Tags: css

I have a dynamic stylesheet which generates the following stylesheet.

```
body {
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
}
div#header_text {
    color: #3a3a3a;
}
div#footer_spacer {
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
}
table#content_container {
    border-top: 6px solid #3a3a3a;
}
iframe#producten_container {
    border-left: 1px solid #3a3a3a;
}
div#footer_text {
    background-color: #646080;
}
#page_title {
    color: #646080;
}
```

This causes parse errors in the CSS validator. The following errors occur:

```
Value background-color Parse Error
Value Error : color Parse Error
Value Error : background-color Parse Error
Value Error : background-color Parse Error
Value Error : color Parse Error
```

I think this CSS looks fine. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here??

Comment: Which CSS validator are you using?

Comment: Works fine for me in the W3C validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *that* snippet of CSS. My best guess is there's some extra weird character(s) in there that shouldn't be. Could you show how you're generating the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

the [w3c validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) lists those as warnings, just to indicate that you are duplicating the same colour in multiple places

you could consolidate some of the colours into a general class to avoid duplication, but as i mentioned the validator just issued warnings at these, not full on errors.